# How to give permission for different users for different pages?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

How can I give access for different users for different page or list or document?

I have admin rights. and when I am giving rights of the page at that time complete application has been shown to that user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Daniel's answer will help you with setting up the permissions for the pages, lists etc. But be warned, the more granular your permissions become on the site, the more difficult it will be to manage permissions on the site. So please spare a thought on this direction as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find lots of information online, for example:

1. [Manage permissions for a list, library, folder, document, or list item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-9d13e7df-a770-4646-91ab-e3c117fcef45#bm2)
2. [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx)
3. [Understand groups and permissions on a SharePoint site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understand-groups-and-permissions-on-a-SharePoint-site-258e5f33-1b5a-4766-a503-d86655cf950d)
4. [Roadmap: Grant permissions for a site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Roadmap-Grant-permissions-for-a-site-10682af5-e6f2-4176-96ab-d990ad143ade)

Comment: Thanks Daniel this information is also help full for me.

Answer (score 3):

In Sharepoint browser,

**For sites:**

> Site Settings > Site permissions > create a new group or add user to existing group

**For document library:**

> Site Libraries and lists > Customize "(document library name)" > Permissions for this document library > create a new group or add user to existing group

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone I found work around for this.
this also can be done using navigation to hide the link button from page and can be customized by admin for particular user.